# Solving indefinite integral $\int \frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration

How can we solve this integration?
$$\int \frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$
I tried to make the following substitution
$$1+x^2=w^2$$
but this substitution complicated the integral.

Comment: Wolfram gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%281%2Bsqrt%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%2Bsqrt%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29) monster of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\tan u$

$$\int \frac{\sec^2u+\sec^3u}{\tan^2u+\sec u}$$

$$\int \frac{\sec^2u+\sec u \tan^2 u +\sec u}{\tan^2u+\sec u}$$

First two terms cancel with the denominator the third term and the denominator think about it

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer of @AmerYR, taking $1+x^2=u^2$
$$I=\int \frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx= \int \sec u ~du + \int \frac{sec u}{\tan^2 u+ sec u} du$$ $$ \implies I =\log (\tan u+ sec~ u)+J(u)$$
Next, using $\sin u=\frac{2 \tan(u/2)}{1+\tan^(u/2)},~~ \cos u= \frac{1-\tan^(u/2)}{1+\tan^2(u/2)}$ and $t=\tan(u/2), dt= sec^2 (u/2) du/2$, we get

$$J=\int \frac{\cos u ~du} {\sin^2 u + \cos u}= \frac{(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)}{4t^2/(1+t^2)^2+(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)} \frac{2dt}{(1+t^2)}$$
$$\implies J= 2 \int \frac{t^2-1}{t^4-4t^2-1} dt= 2 \int \frac{t^2-1}{(t^2+a^2)(t^2-b^2)}  dt = 2 \int \left(\frac{A}{t^2-a^2} + \frac{B}{t^2+b^2} \right) dt$$
$$\implies 2 \left(\frac{A}{2a} \log \frac{t-a}{t+a} + \frac{B}{b} \tan^{-1} \frac{t}{b} \right) +C$$
Here $a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}, b=\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}$, $A=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{5}}$, $B=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}.$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=\sinh u$,

$$I=\int \frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2+\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=
\int \frac{\cosh u+\cosh^2 u}{\cosh^2 u+\cosh u - 1}du = u+K$$

where

$$K=\int \frac{1}{\cosh^2 u+\cosh u-1}\ du$$

Then, substitute $\cosh u = \frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}$

\begin{align}
K=& \ 2\int \frac{t^2-1}{t^4-4t^2-1}\ dt\\
=&\ \frac{1}{\sqrt5}\int\left( \frac{\sqrt5+1}{t^2+\sqrt5-2}+\frac{\sqrt5-1}{t^2-\sqrt5-2}\right)dt\\
=&\ \sqrt{\frac25}\sqrt{\sqrt5+1}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}\>t\right)\\
& - \sqrt{\frac25}\sqrt{\sqrt5-1}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}\>t\right)
\end{align}

Thus

$$I= \sinh^{-1}x +
\sqrt{\frac25(\sqrt5+1)}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}\>t\right)\\
-\sqrt{\frac25(\sqrt5-1)}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}\>t\right)$$

with
$t= \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}$.